# Difference between debugging the release and running the release

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, release

When I generate the **Release** version of my app from Visual Studio (F5 Hotkey), everything is fine. But when I run the executable (exe file in the Release folder), I have a bug. That's so strange.

What are the differences between these two modes of execution ?

Thanks.

Comment: The bug is graphics related. My app basically plots a chart which doesn't show up correctly when executed outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: There are no notable differences, other than timing.  The debugger strongly avoids affecting the execution of a program.  Look for something environmental, like the default working directory of the program not pointing at the same directory.  If you have only one monitor then a debugger can affect the painting behavior of a program when you single step or use breakpoints, generating extra paints.

Comment: The ntdll heap manager modifies its behavior if the process was started under a debugger.

Comment: After troubleshooting, it seems that my particular problem came from trying to access C style array that was not initialized. It seems that debugger "cleaned" that error whereas real execution just failed.

Comment: Object was of type `struct SCustomItem {float T[21][3];}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Application Property Settings, the 'debug' settings and 'release' settings are distinct.

For instance, if I set up a 'server name' and 'default database name' in settings fields, when I compile to 'release' it won't pull in the names that I set while I was in debug.  Therefore, you will need to populate the release settings separately.  You haven't included that detail in your post, but it could easily affect the program session.